# android notification as service

Tags: android, service, notifications, alarm

I'm trying to make application for run notification in specific time. Specific time I'm calculating with very complicated code, but that does not matter now.

For each day notification times is different like as:

> 12/01/12 | 13/01/12 | 14/01/12
>   n1:02:00 | n1:02:05 | n1:02:06
>   n2:07:00 | n2:07:08 | ...
>   n3:12:00 | n3:12:02 | ...
>   n4:14:00 | n4:13:59 | ...
>   n5:20:00 | n5:20:01 | ...

I created two method in Activity class for running Notification in specific time:

```
private void createNotification(final String contentTitle, final String contentText,
        final String tickerText) {

    calculateTimes();
    setFirstMillis(getNextTime());

    createStatusBarNotification(contentTitle, contentText, tickerText);

    Notification note = new Notification(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, VakActivity.class), 0);

    note.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle, contentText, intent);

    note.vibrate = new long[]{1000,1000,1000,1000,1000};
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

    note.sound = Uri.parse(getAlarmTone());

    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, note);
}

private void createStatusBarNotification(final String contentTitle,
        final String contentText, final String tickerText) {

    Date date = new Date(getFirstMillis());

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createNotification(contentTitle, contentText, tickerText);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, date);
}
```

I started createStatusBarNotification method in:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    ...
    ...
    createStatusBarNotification("Title", "Text",
            "tickerText");

}
```

But, I want to start this notification as service.

I try to make a new class

```
public class StartNotificationService extends Service
```

But I do not know what I need write in this class and how, when and from run this class.

---

Update:

I created new method in Activity which I called from onCreate method

```
public void setOneTimeAlarm() {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartNotificationService.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
      am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
}
```

StartNotificationService class:

```
public class StartNotificationService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1234;

    private Pror pror;
    private Context cntx;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        cntx = context;

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


      createStatusBarNotification("Title", "Text",
            "tickerText");
    }

    private void createStatusBarNotification(final String contentTitle,
            final String contentText, final String tickerText) {

        Date date = new Date(pror.getFirstMillis());
        Log.i("date", date.toString());

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createNotification(contentTitle, contentText, tickerText);
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask, date);
    }

    private void createNotification(final String contentTitle, final String contentText,
            final String tickerText) {

        pror.calculateVak();
        pror.setFirstMillis(pror.getNextVak());

        createStatusBarNotification(contentTitle, contentText, tickerText);

        Notification note = new Notification(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(cntx, 0, new Intent(cntx, VakActivity.class), 0);

        note.setLatestEventInfo(cntx, contentTitle, contentText, intent);

        note.vibrate = new long[]{1000,1000,1000,1000,1000};
        note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

        note.sound = Uri.parse(pror.getAlarmTone());

        note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, note);
    }
}
```

**I want to send variable from Activity to StartNotificationService. How can I do that?**

Problem is Pror variable. This variable I set in Activity (read preferences, ...) and I want that instance in StartNotificationService class to.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the AlarmManager: Schedule the alarm for the time you calculated according to your algorithm and send the notification when the alarm is triggered. See here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

If you want to create the alarm inside a service implementation or an activity depends on how a recalculation of the times might be initiated.

Update (wrt. comment below): Why don't you write the value of the pror variable (as string or whatever the Pror type suggests) to the shared preferences and read the shared preferences later when you need the value.

Answer (score 0):

First you should use alarm manager and 
use alarm in service because when service running in background, it will check time when u want to show notification and show notification.
i think it can help something.
thanx